# Jquery .serializeArray() not processing value of dynamically appended combobox

Tags: php, jquery, html, combobox

I am trying to serialize value of form elements, where my combox is dynamicall added after user click.
I'm getting value from static combobox bt nt from dynamic combobox.
my code:

```
  <script>
   //submit data
    $(function (a) {
     $("form").submit(function (event) {
      console.log($(this).serializeArray());
      event.preventDefault();
      });
     });

   // populate entree item to select menu
    function populate() {
      // only declare the variables once
      var json = <?php echo $json; ?>, obj, option = ' ', i;
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        obj = json[i];
         option += '<option value="' + obj.id + '">' + $.trim(obj.title) + '</option>';
        }
      return option;
     }

        //add more select box when addmore click
     $(function (b) {
      var i = 0;
       $("a#addmore").click(function () {
        i++;
        $("p#entree").append('<select name="entree' + i + '">' + populate() + '<select><br>');
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: no checkbox only combobox

Comment: Try closing you select tag. `...+ populate() + '</select><br>'`

Comment: yea, closed it bt still not getting value

Comment: should work, create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl it's working in fiddle bt don't know not working on my page
http://jsfiddle.net/fabulous/636pet64/

Comment: @charlietfl i got the value when i write form code outside the table, bt dont know why the table was blocking the processing.

Comment: could be you are using invalid html. Post sample structure of table and form. for example you can't wrap a `<tr>` in a form

Comment: @charlietfl you mean i cant do this?   `...<table><form><tr><td></td></tr></form></table>`

Comment: No you can't. `<form>` is invalid child of `<table>` so browser is not putting it where you think and that is the whole problem

Comment: @charlietfl okay, already rectified.

Answer (score 0):

i got the value when i put my form outside the table. I dnt know why table is blocking the process to get value.